# how to merge two data frame with out adding duplicates in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe looks like:

```
    x   y   z
1   3   7   1
2   7   5   2
3   8   2   3
```

and other dataframe looks like:

```
    x   y   z
1   7   5   4
2   8   2   8
3   4   5   5
4   7   3   7
5   9   5   3
6   3   7   9
```

Now I want to merge the two frames, and the frame after merge to be looked like this:

```
    x   y   z
1   3   7   1
2   7   5   2
3   8   2   3
4   4   5   5
5   7   3   7
6   9   5   3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) + [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with define columns for check duplicates `x` and `y` + [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for remove duplicated index values:

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(['x','y']).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   x  y  z
0  3  7  1
1  7  5  2
2  8  2  3
3  4  5  5
4  7  3  7
5  9  5  3
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael, that is what i was wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate, then dedupe

```
pandas.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: yes it add all value to the dataframe did not remove duplicates on x and y